# Format moment in React State immmutably

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, datepicker, momentjs

I'm trying to format the moment object in my state to a string before sending to the Database in an immutable way so as not to alter the state.

```
        this.state = {
            startDate: moment()
        }
```

The state needs to be an Object for React DatePicker.
So on Submit of my form I want to change the startDate to a string.

```
        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

             const newState = { 
                ...this.state,  
                startDate : { ...this.state.startDate } 
             };

             newState.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


             this.RegisterEmployeeService.registerEmployee(newState)
             .then((res) => {
                Swal('Registered!');
             })  
        }
```

But I'm getting an error when running '.format()' on the newState.startDate object.

```
          <DatePicker
                selected={this.state.startDate}
                onChange={this.handleStartDateChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Error:

```
      TypeError: newState.startDate.format is not a function
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Apolgies, I included it above

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe it has something to do with `startDate : { ...this.state.startDate }`

Change it to: `startDate : this.state.startDate` and it should work!

That should look like:

```
const newState = { 
    ...this.state,  
    startDate: this.state.startDate
};
```

Comment: The problem with that is that startDate is an object. So I believe I need to use the spread operator to deeply clone the state?

Comment: In that case the best you can do is to use `Object.assign({}, yourObj);` It'll deep clone the object

Answer (score 0):

As Saurabh Sharma suggests, the `{...this.state.startDate}` is going to cause problems.

To get the formatted date into your `newState` variable, I'd suggest you write the `handleSubmit` function like so:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const formattedDate = this.state.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      newState = {
        ...this.state,
        startDate: formattedDate
      }

     this.RegisterEmployeeService.registerEmployee(newState)
     .then((res) => Swal('Registered!'))
}
```

You could also just inline the formattedDate if you don't want another variable:

```
const newState = {
    ...this.state,
    startDate: this.state.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}
```

**- EDIT -**

If you are worried about modifying your existing state unintentionally (which is easy to do with Momentjs), you can clone your existing state using the [ES6 assign method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, ...this.state);
```

What the above does is takes an empty object and clones your state into it.  By doing this you are able to modify `newState` as much as you'd like without touching the original `this.state`:

```
newState.startDate = newState.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: In this implementation I would not be deeply cloning the state? startDate is an object, so that is why I was using the spread operator on the state and startDate. 

Does format() change the state or does it create a new variable from the state?

Comment: @Fraser I made an edit above, to protect your state from modification, I could clone it using the Object.assign method.